# Angular 7 shared service is not shared

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am new to angular and I am trying to pass data from one component(HomeComponent) to another component(ProfileComponent) after navigation.

I created a shared service(DataService).
I injected the service in both the HomeComponent and ProfileComponent but when I set the value of the message property in HomeComponent and try to retrieve it in the ProfileComponent the value is undefined because the DataService is not the same instance.

The DataService was registered in the AppModule in the providers array so it should be a shared service and always the same instance right?

Thanks in advance

**DataService.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  message:string;

  constructor() { }
}
```

**HomeComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.message = "hello world";
  }

}
```

**ProfileComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  private message : string;//undefined

  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.data.message;
  }

}
```

**AppModule.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DataService } from './services/data/data.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: [Something for you to look at](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) if you want to do this properly.

Comment: @R.Richards thank you for the article. The difference is the article is about passing data when there is a parent-child relationship. In my case there is no parent-child relationship between HomeComponent and ProfileComponent. I navigate from HomeComponent to ProfileComponent.

Comment: You should either use the "providedIn" property on the service's @Injectable decorator or name the service in the AppModule's "providers" section, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you inject the service to your component, new instance is generated. However in this case i would recommend you to use BehaviorSubject as follows,

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-example-dsxnnc?file=app%2FdataService.ts)**

Comment: thank you for your reply, I looked at the stackblitz demo and I tried to implement it in my code, but when i navigate from my HomeComponent to my ProfileComponent I still get the default message. I don't know what the problem is I call my changeMessage function in my HomeComponent.

Comment: can you produce a stackblitz

Comment: here is my stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fztyb5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

Comment: problem here is you are refreshing the route, so everything will be cleared . you need localstorage or ngrx here

Comment: So if i want to pass data from one route to another I need to another route I need to use localstorage or ngrx? I have seen the example that u posted above multiple times but all the examples were for components on the same route. Is localstorage and ngrx the only way to pass data between two components on two different routes?

Comment: no i am talking only about your example. you have to manually change the url address and refresh the page in order to see the change in route. if you are navigating by code you can use the same approach as above

Comment: so if I used to the Router class to navigate it would work?

Comment: Thank you for your help I didn't knew there was a difference between navigating with the Router class and navigating by changing the url. I was thinking to add a button to navigate by code but i thought it didn't matter.Again thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a 2 year question, but Google puts it at the top of search results

Now, Angular docs are clearer about this (or just we can find out easier), it's called "[Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)"
The section that explains this "bug" is [The ForRoot Pattern](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern) and it says:

"If a module defines both providers and declarations (components, directives, pipes), then loading the module in multiple feature modules would duplicate the registration of the service. This could result in multiple service instances and the service would no longer behave as a singleton."

To sum up, if you define this in your services (**DataService.ts**) the `providedIn: root` as follows

`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

you need to avoid define the service as a provider on your components or modules.

**AppModule.ts**

```js
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService], // This line is the problem
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
....
```

Hope that helps to somebody and if need more documentation refer to Singleton Services' link